# Which Mac models included a software visible DSP chip

Tags: hardware

Which Mac models included a DSP chip that could be accessed by regular application code? (e.g. not hidden inside the mouse, WiFi chip, disk read/write chip, GPU, etc.)

Did they ship before or after the Next Cube?

Answer (score 7):

The [Quadra 660AV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Quadra_660AV) and [Quadra 840AV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Quadra_840AV) had AT&T 3210 DSPs, and as far as I know were the only Macs to include a DSP as standard. The DSP was used by [PlainTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlainTalk) for speech recognition.

They were both released in 1993, well after [the NeXTcube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTcube) which was released in 1990, and [the original NeXT Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXT_Computer) which was released in 1988 and already had a Motorola 56001 DSP.

Comment: Since other brands are mentioned, I'll add Atari Falcon; released in 1992, included Motorola 56001 DSP.

Comment: ... as did the SGI Indigo (1991).